# JS upload cropper with two instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to upload a second `img` to the cropper that populates the second `.img-result`. The cropper should populae whatever was uploaded, and then when the `save btn` is pressed, the `.img-result` is updated.

I added the attribute `data-up` but I'm not sure how to call it in the JS.

```js
// vars
var result = document.querySelector('.result'),
  img_result = document.querySelector('.img-result'),
  img_w = document.querySelector('.img-w'),
  img_h = document.querySelector('.img-h'),
  options = document.querySelector('.options'),
  save = document.querySelector('.save'),
  cropped = document.querySelector('.cropped'),
  upload = document.querySelector('.file'),
  cropper = '';

// on change show image with crop options
upload.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (e.target.files.length) {
    // start file reader
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      if (e.target.result) {
        // create new image
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.id = 'image';
        img.src = e.target.result;
        // clean result before
        result.innerHTML = '';
        // append new image
        result.appendChild(img);
        // init cropper
        cropper = new Cropper(img);
      }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
  }
});

// save on click
save.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // get result to data uri
  var imgSrc = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
    width: img_w.value // input value
  }).toDataURL();
  // show image cropped
  cropped.src = imgSrc;
});
```

```css
.img-result {
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.img-result img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.result {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

.box-2 {
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: calc(100%/2 - 1em);
}

.img-w {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/0.8.1/cropper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.4/cropper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="page">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="options">
      <input type="number" class="img-w" value="300" min="100" max="1200" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn save">Save</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <input class="file" type="file" id="file-input" data-up="1">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <input class="file" type="file" id="file-input" data-up="2">
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <div class="result"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="result">
    <div class="box-2 img-result">
      <img class="cropped" src="" alt="" data-up="1">
    </div>
    <div class="box-2 img-result">
      <img class="cropped" src="" alt="" data-up="2">
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: `id="file-input"` _identifiers_ must be unique

Comment: and use `document.getElementById('file-input1).getAttribute('data-up')`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as I mentioned in comments. `Id` must be for each element of your `DOM`. So, you better change `id="file-input"` to `id="file-input1"` and so on.

And It looks like you want to get the attribute value `data-up` when `save` function called,

You can do that in this way

```
save.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // get result to data uri
   document.getElementById('file-input1).getAttribute('data-up')
....
```

Comment: Thanks George. Are you able to add an embed with a working example? It will help me a lot.